# How to replace tabs with?

Tags: c#

How to replace tabs with ? I try it like this:

```
foreach (var url in urlList)
            {
                try
                {
                    stopwatch.Start();
                    requester.DownloadString(url);
                    url.Replace("\n",string.Empty);
                    if (url.Contains("/select/"))
                    {
                        url.Replace(string.Empty, "?");
                    }


                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("An error occured while attempting to connect to {0}", url);
                }
                finally
                {
                    stopwatch.Stop();

                    //We use the counter for a friendlier url as the current ones are unwieldly
                    times.Add("Url " + counter, stopwatch.Elapsed);
                    counter++;

                    stopwatch.Reset();
                }
            }
```

But this: url.Replace("\n","?"); doesnt do the job. So how to manage that? My post has to much code. But I dont have text to type

Thank you

---

this is the complete code:

```
public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            //Consider making this configurable
            const string sourceFile = "testSolar.txt";

            var requester = new WebClient();
            var times = new Dictionary<string, TimeSpan>();
            var stopwatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();

            //Add header so if headers are tracked, it will show it is your application rather than something ambiguous
            requester.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "Response-Tester-Client");

            var urlList = new List<string>();

            //Loop through the lines in the file to get the urls 
            try
            {
                stopwatch.Start();
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(sourceFile))
                {

                    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        urlList.Add(reader.ReadLine());
                        urlList.Remove("\n");

                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An error occured while attempting to access the source file at {0}", sourceFile);
            }
            finally
            {
                //Stop, record and reset the stopwatch
                stopwatch.Stop();
                times.Add("FileReadTime", stopwatch.Elapsed);
                stopwatch.Reset();
            }

            //Try to connect to each url
            var counter = 1;
            foreach (var url in urlList)
            {
                try
                {
                    stopwatch.Start();
                    requester.DownloadString(url);
                     url.Replace("\t","?");
                    if (url.Contains("/select/"))
                    {
                        url.Replace(string.Empty, "?");
                    }


                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("An error occured while attempting to connect to {0}", url);
                }
                finally
                {
                    stopwatch.Stop();

                    //We use the counter for a friendlier url as the current ones are unwieldly
                    times.Add("Url " + counter, stopwatch.Elapsed);
                    counter++;

                    stopwatch.Reset();
                }
            }

            //Release the resources for the WebClient 
            requester.Dispose();

            //Write the response times
            foreach (var key in times.Keys)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", key, times[key].TotalSeconds);
            }


            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

---

This was doing the work:

```
while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        var line = reader.ReadLine();
                        line =  line.Replace("\t", "?");
                        urlList.Add(line);
                    }
```

Comment: replace "\t" for tab

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A tab string is represent by `\t`.
So if you want to replace tab by question mark:

```
url.Replace("\t","?");
```

Should do the job.

Edit:
Right, as explain by Zaheer Ahmed, you need also to reaffect the result of the Replace function...

Comment: Thank You, But I mean replace tabs with the question mark(?)

Comment: Same here. Hope it helps anyway.

Comment: Same for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Issue here is you are not re-assinging the string back to variable:

```
url = url.Replace("\n",string.Empty);
```

and to replace tabs try \t as mentioned by others:

```
url = url.Replace("\t","?");
```